# Entity Framework CTP5 Code-First: Mapping a class with multiple collections of another class

Tags: .net, entity-framework, code-first, entity-framework-ctp5, ef-code-first

With EF CTP5 Code-First I am trying to map a class model which contains multiple collections in one class pointing to another class. Here is an example of what I mean:

```
public class Company
{
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public IList<Person> FemaleEmployees { get; set; }
    public IList<Person> MaleEmployees { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

If I let the database create from this model with a `DbContext` without further customization, like so:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
}
```

... then I get two tables in SQL Server, a simple `Companies` table with only a `CompanyId` column and a `People` table with the following columns ("FKRN" means "Foreign Key Relationship Name", as created by EF in SQL Server):

```
PersonId            int     not nullable
CompanyCompanyId    int     nullable       FKRN: Company_FemaleEmployees
CompanyCompanyId1   int     nullable       FKRN: Company_MaleEmployees
CompanyCompanyId2   int     nullable       FKRN: Person_Company
```

The last three columns have all a foreign key relationship to the primary key `CompanyId` of the `Companies` table.

Now I have several questions:

- 1) Why do I get **three** foreign key columns in the `People` table? I actually expected two. If I remove the property `public Company Company { get; set; }` from the `Person` the third column `CompanyCompanyId2` disappears but I also lose the reference property in the class.
- 2) Let's say I drop the `Company` property from the `Person` table (I don't need it really in my model). Is there a way to give the two remaining foreign key columns another name than the auto-created `CompanyCompanyId` and `CompanyCompanyId1`? (For instance `FCompanyId` and `MCompanyId` to indicate the relation to the `FemaleEmployees` and `MaleEmployees` collections.)
- 3) Is there any way to define this model with only one foreign key `CompanyId` in the `People` table? Surely I would need a differentiating additional column in the `Person` class (like `bool IsFemale`). A Person is either part of the `FemaleEmployees` or the `MaleEmployees` collection, never in both (naturally in this example), so with SQL I could fetch those collections by something like `WHERE IsFemale = true/false AND CompanyId = 1`. I am wondering if I could give EntityFramework a hint to load the two collections this way. (Here I would like to avoid to extend the model by a `FemalePerson` and `MalePerson` class which both derive from `Person` as base class and then use for instance Table-Per-Hierarchy mapping, since these derived classes would be empty and artificial and had no other purpose except enabling the mapping to SQL Server.) Having only one foreign key `CompanyId` would allow me to make it `non-nullable` which isn't possible with two foreign keys (both can never be non-null in the same row).

Thank you for feedback and suggestions in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- To question (1): EF cannot map the single reference property `Company` in class `Person` to two different collection endpoints `FemaleEmployees` and `MaleEmployees` in class `Company` at the same time. The mapping conventions assume that there is actually a third endpoint in `Company` which isn't exposed in the model. Therefore a third foreign key is created.
- To question (2): With the [EF 4.1 Release Candidate](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/15/ef-4-1-release-candidate-available.aspx) it is now possible to specify the database column name of foreign keys in the Fluent API (which wasn't possible with EF CTP5) by using the `Map` method of the `ForeignKeyNavigationPropertyConfiguration` class:

  ```
  modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
              .HasMany(c => c.FemaleEmployees)
              .WithOptional()
              .Map(conf => conf.MapKey("FCompanyId"))
              .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

  modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
              .HasMany(c => c.MaleEmployees)
              .WithOptional()
              .Map(conf => conf.MapKey("MCompanyId"))
              .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
  ```
- To question (3): I still have no idea.

**Edit**

Just to close this old question now: (3) (relating two navigation properties in one entity to the same endpoint of another entity) is not possible, for example: [Specific Entity Framework Code First Many to 2 Model Mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342848/specific-entity-framework-code-first-many-to-2-model-mapping/5343570#5343570) ... (and I remember many other questions which were looking for a solution for such a scenario without success)

Answer (score 2):

I think you could do this:

```
public class Company
{
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Person> Employees { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Person> MaleEmployees {
        get
        {
            Employees.Where(x=> !x.IsFemale);
        }
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

You just have one CompanyID FK at People table.

You can load Male Employees using EF context:

```
context.Entry(companyInstance)
    .Collection(p => p.Employees)
    .Query()
    .Where(u => !u.IsFemale)
    .Load();
```

I think that your approach isn´t so good, because, what happens when I add a male to Company.FemaleEmployees? EF dont know this rules

Comment: Thanks for reply! I tried something similar (3 collections, one total collection (as you also have in your example) which is mapped to DB and 2 additional collections (male and female) which are marked as `Ignored` in the model. But it started to become complicated to keep the collections in sync when I add, remove, update objects and read/write/delete from DB. In my domain I never need the total collection, only the two split collections. So having this total collection is very artificial and would only be my last resort if there is no other way to make the collections persistent with EF.

Comment: Male/FemaleEmployees is only an example which represents the same structure as my domain model. The case that I could add a male into the FemaleCollection (or vice versa) can never happen in my domain. Think about the fact that you do NOT have an `IsFemale` flag on the person class: Then, being in the FemaleEmployees collection, is the DEFINITION of a Person to be female. It can never be wrong from the data model viewpoint. Of course, someone could move Jennifer Lopez into the MaleEmployees collection, but that would be the same kind of user mistake as setting an IsFemale flag to false.

Comment: Maybe you can force relationship with modelBuilder.Entity<Company>() 
    .HasMany(c => c.FemaleEmployees) 
    .WithRequired(p => p.Company)

Comment: I tried this. If I do this only for one of the collections it doesn't make a difference. If I do this for both collections I get exceptions telling me that the schema is invalid.