# Specific Entity Framework Code First Many to 2 Model Mapping

Tags: entity-framework, foreign-keys, ef-code-first

I'm a bit of a loss here.

Basically I have these two Models:

```
public class Player
{
    public int PlayerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Game> Games { get; set; }
}

public class Game
{
    public int GameId { get; set; }

    public virtual Player PlayerBlack { get; set; }
    public virtual Player PlayerWhite { get; set; }
}
```

Now the Database Schema, EF Code First creates for me, is not correct because the Game table gets 3 Foreign Keys (Playerblack, PlayerWhite and Player) instead of 2.

So how can I tie these Models together so that EF understands that the Players Games are found by either looking at the Black or White Player.

Basically each time I call *myPlayer.Games* EF has to look into PlayerBlack AND PlayerWhite Foreign Keys.

Is it even possible?

Comment: BTW: Similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067688/entity-framework-ctp5-code-first-mapping-a-class-with-multiple-collections-of-an While you are tyring to map two references to one collection, I was looking there to map two collections to one reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's not possible. You cannot have an association with a single endpoint on one side and two endpoints on the other side of the relation.

Possible workarounds:

- Use two collections in the `Player` class:

  ```
  public virtual ICollection<Game> GamesAsBlackPlayer { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Game> GamesAsWhitePlayer { get; set; }
  ```

  Depending on your context you could perhaps merge these collections together to a readonly collection `Games` which is not mapped to the database.

(Edit: Proposed second workaround was crap, deleted now.)

Edit2: Another workarund could be to extend you class model by an additional class `PlayerInGame`:

```
public class Player
{
    public int PlayerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PlayerInGame> PlayerInGames { get; set; }

    // optional helper property
    [NotMapped]
    public IEnumerable<Game> Games
    {
        get
        {
            return PlayerInGames.Select(g => g.Game);
        }
    }
}

public class Game
{
    public int GameId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PlayerInGame> PlayersInGame { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public Player PlayerBlack
    {
        get
        {
            return PlayersInGame.Single(p => p.WhiteOrBlack == "B").Player;
        }
    }

    [NotMapped]
    public Player PlayerWhite
    {
        get
        {
            return PlayersInGame.Single(p => p.WhiteOrBlack == "W").Player;
        }
    }
}

public class PlayerInGame
{
    public int PlayerInGameId { get; set; }

    public virtual Game Game { get; set; }
    public virtual Player Player { get; set; }
    public string WhiteOrBlack { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see by the `Single` method in the `PlayerBlack` and `PlayerWhite` properties in the `Game` class you have to make sure in your business logic to create the proper `PlayerInGame` entities so that your `PlayersInGame` collection always has two elements with Black or White flag respectively.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I went with your first idea and getting all games with: `public IEnumerable<Game> Games { get { return GamesAsBlackPlayer.Concat(GamesAsWhitePlayer).ToList(); } }`

Comment: Ah, Concat! I didn't even know that this method exists. (I had "AddRange" on a List in mind, but Concat seems to be more general. Nice!)

Answer (score -1):

I would tackle the problem like this:

```
public abstract class Player
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

public class WhitePlayer : Player
{
}

public class BlackPlayer : Player
{
}

public class Game
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public virtual WhitePlayer WhitePlayer { get; set; }
    public virtual BlackPlayer BlackPlayer { get; set; }
}

public class GamePlayerContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Game> Games { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Player> Players { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your solution is not correct, because the same player will be sometimes black and sometimes white. An object can't change its type.